# How to fill a report dynamically?

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports

I have to generate  reports from my application,
first the user choose his search criteria then he validate his choice (search criteria:type of charts ,group by  , etc)
My question is: how can I construct my report?
My idea is:

1-declar String SQL

2- when a user check a search criteria I'll concat his choice to the sql request
eg:

String sql;
String select="select";
String from="from";
String where;="where"
String and="and";
String GroupBY="Group by";

when he choose Calculate number of...groupby....
I will concat:
select= select+ "count(*)" etc

ALSO

I'am using mapping JPA/Hibernate so I don't use connection to database from my code(I mean I don't declar explicitly con=connection....),so what should I pass to the methods .fillReportToFile,runReportToPdfStream ,etc

Comment: way too little info here for an answer. What I would say however is that what you've said so far sounds like a recipe for SQL-injection attacks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Why not just figure out the types of queries that the user might make and then hard-code as much of the query as possible?  For example, you can have String count_query="select count(1) from ", and then you can process count_query + "whatever_table_the_user_wants", and likewise for other queries?  I should also add that if this is not an internal application, you'll obviously want to do some parsing to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: it's just an idea I haven't try it :)

Answer (score 0):

I generally implement [JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html) and do not include any SQL in my report at all. That way you can take the parameters for the report generation and feed the results to Jasper reports directly in a controlled way.

If generating a report with embedded sub-reports then you may still need to supply a connection.

```
/* Where datasource is your data supplier */
JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameterMap, dataSource);
```

Comment: So I should use Java object as a datasource , I have searched in the Net and I haven't found a good example :(

Comment: When you want to run the report with the custom SQL, you run a JDBC query (or a Hibernate query) and create an instance of class that implements JRDataSource passing it your resultset in the constructor. Then you just implement the two methods in your class using the resultset and pass that object to the fillReport method as shown above. Its really easy.